# How do I prove the universal mapping property of the field of quotients?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Reference : [http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/54.html](http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Ebeachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/54.html)

> Theorem 5.4.6
>
> Let $R$ be an integral domain and $Q(R)$ be the field of quotients of $R$.
>
> Let $F$ be a field.
>
> Let $\phi:R\rightarrow  F$ be a ring monomorphism.
>
> Then, there exists a unique ring monomorphism $\Phi:Q(R)\rightarrow F$ such that $\Phi(x)=\phi(x)$ on $R$.

I have constructed $\Phi$ as $\Phi(a/_Q b)=\phi(a)/_F \phi(b)$, and I have shown that $\Phi$ is a right monomorphism.

However, I'm not sure how to show that $\Phi(x)=\phi(x)$ on $R$.

THat is;

Fix $x\in R$.

Then, $\Phi(x)=\Phi(x/_Q 1_R) = \phi(x)/_F \phi(1_R)$.

How do I show that $\phi(1_R)$ is $1_F$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You work with the class (more precisely: category) of rings with unit, therefore with homomorphisms preserving the unit.

Comment: @MartinBrandenbrug So do you mean I have to add an additional hypothesis that is $\phi(1_R)=1_F$?

Comment: This doesn't have to be added, it *is there*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism